# Component not rerendering on state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Whenever setState() is called, the component doesn't seem to rerender. As you can see by my comments, the state does in fact change and render seems to be called again, but if I don't add that if statement and simply add a paragraph tag that displays the data it will give me an error. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but any help is appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { constants } from "../constants/constants";
const { baseURL, apiKey, userName } = constants;

class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    user: []
  };
}
componentDidMount() {
  let getUserInfo = axios.create({
    baseURL,
    url: `? 
    method=user.getinfo&user=${userName}&api_key=${apiKey}&format=json`
   });
  getUserInfo().then(response => {
  let data = response.data;
  console.log(data.user.playcount); //logs second, displays correct
  this.setState(state => ({
    user: data
  }));
});
}

render() {
  console.log(this.state); //logs first and third, doesn't work on first but does on third
  let toReturn;
  if (this.state.user.length > 0) {
    toReturn = <p>{this.state.user.user.playcount}</p>;
  } else {
    toReturn = <p>didn't work</p>;
  }
  return <div>{toReturn}</div>;
  }
}

export default User;
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  Why are you sending `state` into your `setState` function?

Comment: @jmargolisvt when calling `setState` if you pass in a callback instead of an object, you are given the current state to use for updating, but his example doesn't do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem might have something to do with the changing shape of the `user` value. You initialise the value to an empty array, but then—after the fetch is done—you assume it's an object (by using `user.user`).

Maybe you could simplify the code a bit to look more like the one below?

```
/* imports */

class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: null // Make it explicit there's no value at the beginning.
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let getUserInfo = axios.create(/* ... */);
    getUserInfo().then(response => {
      let data = response.data;
      this.setState({ // No need to for a setter function as you dno't rely on the previous state's value.
        user: data.user // Assign the user object as the new value.
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    let toReturn;
    // Since it's now a `null`, you can use a simple existence check.
    if (this.state.user) {
      // User is now an object, so you can safely refer to its properties.
      toReturn = <p>{this.state.user.playcount}</p>;
    } else {
      toReturn = <p>No data yet.</p>;
    }
    return <div>{toReturn}</div>;
  }
}

export default User;
```

Answer (score 2):

React LifeCycle function sequence is Constructor and then it calls render method.
In constructor method it initialises the state which is currently empty user array.
Now it calls render() method as this.state.user is an empty array, referencing something out of it gives an error

```
this.state.user.user.playcount
```

this will generate an error if you dont have if condition.
After the first render it will call componentDidMount, now you fetch something update state. As setState occurred, render will be called again Now you have something in this.state.user then displaying will  happen.

```
this.state.user.length > 0 is true
```

Look at this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

You can right in single

tag using conditional render like this

```
<p>{this.state.user.length ? this.state.user.user.playcount : 'loading'}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've added the conditional rendering, but it only says loading and never changes

Comment: So data you received from API is an array? Did you check any console errors?

Comment: Data is returned as json, and there were no console errors